# Moving SKSpriteNode to direction of touch

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

Here you have an printscreen of the game:

[image]

I have a static SKSpriteNode(the player) that is rotating to the direction of the touch. This is the code I have for that:

```
class GameplayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

static let Pi = CGFloat(Double.pi)
static let DegreesToRadians = Pi / 180

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
UIEvent?) {
    let curTouch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let curPoint = curTouch.location(in: self)

    let deltaX = self.player.position.x - curPoint.x
    let deltaY = self.player.position.y - curPoint.y
    let angle = atan2(deltaY, deltaX)

    self.player.zRotation = angle + 90 * GameplayScene.DegreesToRadians
}
}
```

Now, I want to shoot bullets every second from the player that moves in the same direction as the touch of the screen. When the bullet moves outside of the screen, I want to implement "SKAction.removeFromParent".

Here is my fireMissile function:

```
func fireMissile() {
    let missile = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellow, size: CGSize(width: 20, 
    height: 5))
    missile.name = "Missile"
    missile.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x + 30, y: 
    player.position.y)
    missile.zPosition = 2
    missile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: missile.size)
    missile.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    missile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Bullet
    missile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy
    missile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy

    self.addChild(missile)

}
```

Comment: Didn't I already give you this answer?

Comment: confused, or are you asking two different questions here? do you need help removing the bullet, or help rotating the tank? or help moving the tank? These are all separate questions :)

Comment: Fluidify - I want to make bullets shoot(from the player) in the direction of the touch on the screen with a constant speed, basically. Sorry for not beeing clear on that :P

Comment: make sure you use @Name so we get notified :) I only happened upon this question again...

Answer (score 1):

For the timer, you'll want to use this:

```
run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run {
        yourFunction()
        }, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)])), withKey: "key")
```

As for the missile shooting, add SKActions in sequential order. The first should put the bullet in front of your player, the second would move the missile, and third would delete, but this will only run after the other lines due to the sequence. Make sure you have a key to this sequence if you want to stop it later mid animation. Should look something like this:

```
missile.zRotation = player.zRotation
missile.position = CGPoint(x:player.size.width/2*cos(player.zRotation)+player.position.x ,y:player.size.height*sin(player.zRotation)+player.position.y)
 missile.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:frame.size.width*cos(player.zRotation)+player.position.x ,y:frame.size.height*sin(player.zRotation)+player.position.y), duration: 0.5), SKAction.removeFromParent()]), withKey: "move")
```

Comment: The run at the end might have a slight syntax error, but you could probably fix that

Comment: You do not want to use `Timer` with sprite kit, you want to use the built in timing methods via actions

Comment: Thanks Bruce - Yes, I did have a syntax issue in the last line saying "Type '([SKAction]) -> SKAction' has no subscript member". No, haven't solved that :/

Comment: Use this line: missile.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:frame.size.width*cos(player.zRotation)+player.position.x ,y:frame.size.height*sin(player.zRotation)+player.position.y), duration: 0.5), SKAction.removeFromParent()]), withKey: "move") and yeah follow Knight's advice as his method allows better control

Comment: update your answer to use SKAction instead of timer, and you will get +1s :)

Comment: @Fluidity I gotchu